# Hash value calculation on Pen Drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hash

I am trying to calculate Hash value on "PEN Drive". When i attach my pen-drive to my-pc(Linux-Ubuntu 12.04) and calculate hash and it give me 128bit(32 character length) string. I remove pen-drive and attach in another PC(Linux-Ubuntu 12.04) it give me different Hash value. I have not made any change even then it give me different value. So why this happen or how can i solve this? 
I am using "md5sum" for calculate hash value.

Comment: Use `md5sum` on individual files. Don't forget to `sync` before removing your USB storage drive.

Comment: Thanks @Basile Starynkevitch I can do it like you suggest. But my requirement is that I have to generate only one hash for whole Device(PEN DRIVE) or may in near future i need to calculate on HDD(Size: 80GB,160GB or may be more). if i understand correctly then are you trying to say that 1. figure out all files 2. Calculate hash on each file. 3. and combine it in one . is this scenario?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Are you sure it makes some sense?